# How to highlight a specific date in Bootstrap date picker

Tags: angularjs, bootstrap-datepicker

When I am trying to open the date picker, a specific date that I will get from some other system should be highlighted.

I am using the below options/attributes for my bootstrap datepicker.

```
ele.datepicker({
                autoclose: true,
                keyboardNavigation: false,
                todayHighlight: true,
                format: 'YYYY-MM-DD',
                clearBtn: true,
            });
```

I tried different options available from the documentation but none worked for my purpose.

- https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/options.html

I want to set a date like setDate: '2021-10-13' in the options or some other way so that when I click on the date filed it should open date picker dialog with 10th month of 2021 with 13th day highlighted.

Please help me achieve this. Thanks.

Comment: After you initiated your datepicker create a new Date like `var highlight_date = new Date (2021, 10, 13);` and then call `ele.datepicker ('update', highlight_date);`. Does this work?

Comment: I tried this but not working.